# multiple html sections, check what section I am on

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arrays

I have 2 HTML sections, they both have the same id (out of my hands, third part cms)

I am currently running some simple code to see how many html section with this ID there is.

How could I set the get array object I am clicking on ?

**My js to see how many sections with same ID**

so I would like a way that i can `console.log(arrayItem)` and see what array object i clicked on.

```
var elms = document.querySelectorAll("[id='sectorpage-strengths']");

    for(var i = 0; i < elms.length; i++)

    console.log(elms);
    console.log(elms[i]);
```

Comment: To get the element you're clicking on, add an [event listener to it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). It should be noted, however, that this is a very hacky solution to a much bigger problem caused by invalid HTML generated from your CMS. That's the issue you should be spending time fixing.

Comment: yeah, however I cant fix that for now. but its on my list to fix later next year

Comment: Please expand upon what you mean by: "How could I set the get array object I am clicking on ?". What is your end goal here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this and get the `this` object

```js
$('[id="sectorpage-strengths"]').click(function(){

var obj = $(this).text();

console.log("Click Event Triggered By " + obj);

});
```

```css
section{
border: solid 1px red;
width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="sectorpage-strengths">Section 1</section>
<section id="sectorpage-strengths">Section 2</section>
```

Comment: The selector will only select the *first* element that matches the id attribute.
update: I was incorrect, this is only the case when you directly use an ID Selector and not the attribute selector

Comment: @BenSewards, It will selects all the matching element and it is working. Please click on sections

Comment: @BenSewards as this uses the attribute it will select all elements with that `id`. It's still far from a workable solution though

Comment: good point, did not realize this was using attribute selector and not directly jquery #id selector